# How could I specify the file name of the Qt Designer Form class by CMake(qt5_wrap_ui)

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

Following are the command I am using(automoc do not work for mu) which work perfectly

```
qt5_wrap_ui(import_dialog_ui ${HW_DATA_DIR}/import_dialog.ui)
qt5_wrap_ui(main_win_ui ${HW_DATA_DIR}/main_window.ui)
qt5_wrap_ui(user_list_ui ${HW_DATA_DIR}/user_list.ui)
```

Project layout

```
Project
  --incl
  --src
  --data(The path of HW_DATA_DIR)
```

The problem is, the original command will generate the file name as

1. ui_import_dialog.h
2. ui_main_window.h
3. ui_user_list.h

But what I want are

1. import_dialog_ui.h
2. main_window_ui.h
3. user_list_ui.h

How could I achieve this by cmake?Thanks

Comment: why not using e.g. `#include "ui_import_dialog.h` in your import_dialog.cpp file?

Comment: @thomas_b Because our manager ask us to name the file as "import_dialog_ui.h" but not "ui_import_dialog.h"

Comment: Just to get it right. `qt5_wrap_ui` generates the ui source files in the build dir which has nothing to do with the real project sourc files. The only point where these will have "contact" is the `#include` statement. Your (project) manager wants this `#include` statement look nicer with ..._ui instead of ui_...?

Comment: @thomas_b The Qt5 is compiled(incomplete) by our engineers(qmake do not work at all), they do not know the default naming convention of Qt, so they come up one by themselves, I do not think they have any will to change it since our build systems are pretty fragile and complicated(we have our own build system, but I would like to throw it away if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you really want to change the name of the output files of the `qt5_wrap_ui` function, you could make a custom version which is effectively a copy of the existing one. This is located in your Qt installation under `lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsMacros.cmake` and looks like this:

```
include(CMakeParseArguments)

# qt5_wrap_ui(outfiles inputfile ... )

function(QT5_WRAP_UI outfiles )
    set(options)
    set(oneValueArgs)
    set(multiValueArgs OPTIONS)

    cmake_parse_arguments(_WRAP_UI "${options}" "${oneValueArgs}" "${multiValueArgs}" ${ARGN})

    set(ui_files ${_WRAP_UI_UNPARSED_ARGUMENTS})
    set(ui_options ${_WRAP_UI_OPTIONS})

    foreach(it ${ui_files})
        get_filename_component(outfile ${it} NAME_WE)
        get_filename_component(infile ${it} ABSOLUTE)
        set(outfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ui_${outfile}.h)
        add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${outfile}
          COMMAND ${Qt5Widgets_UIC_EXECUTABLE}
          ARGS ${ui_options} -o ${outfile} ${infile}
          MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${infile} VERBATIM)
        list(APPEND ${outfiles} ${outfile})
    endforeach()
    set(${outfiles} ${${outfiles}} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

For this, take the code from the `Qt5WidgetsMacros.cmake` file and store it in another file e.g. `Qt5Customizations.cmake`. All you have to do is to rename the function name to something that highlights your customization:

```
function(QT5_WRAP_UI outfiles )
```

change it to e.g.:

```
function(QT5_WRAP_UI_CUSTOM outfiles )
```

And you have to change the line, where the output ui file is stored from:

```
set(outfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ui_${outfile}.h)
```

to
    set(outfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${outfile}_ui.h)

If you now include your custom CMake script in your project's CMake script with:

```
include( Qt5Customizations )
```

you can now use your customized function with:

```
qt5_wrap_ui_custom(import_dialog_ui ${HW_DATA_DIR}/import_dialog.ui)
```

and include the generated ui file with

```
#include "import_dialog_ui.h"
```